# Slowly turning a rectangle in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I have some code:

```
 mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
 angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(mouseY - self.rect.centery, mouseX - self.rect.centerx))
 rotated = pygame.transform.rotate(self.rect, -angle)
 self.rect = lol.get_rect()
```

How should I modify this code to slowly turn the rectangle depending on the mouse angle (10deg/s etc.)?

**Edit:** I want to rotate **CLASS** object (based on pygame.sprite.Sprite class)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't rotate your image to the target angle, but only a little bit until you reach the target angle.

Here's a very simple example. The arrow will slowly follow the mouse:

```
import pygame, math, base64
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))

img = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFEAAADUAAAAXgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAhQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAdwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAApwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAnwAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAxQAAAAYAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAywAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABLAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA3QAAABUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhgAAAK0AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA7wAAACAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA7wAAAC8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAUgAAAFMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAGQAAAAAAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAIAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAggAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAGUAAAAAAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAPoAAABUAAAAAAAAAAAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAPgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAA7wAAADAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIcAAACHAAAAhwAAAIYAAACtAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAPAAAAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEsAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADdAAAAFQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAywAAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAMUAAAAGAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAACgAAAABQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAAqAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABQAAAATwAAAP8AAADTAAAATwAAAHgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAAAADTAAAATwAAAP8AAACFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAUAAAAP8AAADTAAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABRAAAATgAAAF4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD4AAAA7AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=='

surf = pygame.image.fromstring(base64.b64decode(img, 'UTF-8'), (32, 32), 'RGBA')

def rot_center(image, angle):
    orig_rect = image.get_rect()
    rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)
    rot_rect = orig_rect.copy()
    rot_rect.center = rot_image.get_rect().center
    rot_image = rot_image.subsurface(rot_rect).copy()
    return rot_image

current_angle = 0

while True:
    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): break
    pygame.event.get()

    mouseX, mouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    rect = surf.get_rect(center=(92, 92))
    target_angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(mouseY - rect.centery, mouseX - rect.centerx))

    if current_angle > target_angle:
        current_angle -= 0.01
    if current_angle < target_angle:
        current_angle += 0.01 

    screen.fill((40, 140, 40))
    screen.blit(rot_center(surf, -current_angle), rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

[image]

Comment: @ignasaskielasas please don't edit my code if you don't know what you're doing.