# How do I draw a line for a few seconds on mouse click

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I want a line to be drawn and rendered (for a second) when the mouse has been clicked. My example is of a game that shoots a laser or spell etc from the player to an enemy on a mouse click.

My class for the spell:

```
class Magic():
    def __init__(self, mana=100):
        self.mana = mana
        self.recharge = 1
        self.mana_cost  = 5

    def recharge_rate(self):
        pass

    def magic_render(self,mouse_pos):
        pygame.draw.line(game_display,mg,(player.x,player.y),(mouse_pos),5)
        print('fire')
```

My game loop:

```
magic = Magic()
     while run_game == True: # main game loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print('GoodBye')
                run_game = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                magic.magic_render(mouse_pos)

        game_display.fill(bg)
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(fps)
```

I cut out other parts of the program, but currently I can move my player around but when I click the mouse, no line is being shown, but if I remove the line `game_display.fill(bg)`, then I can see the line being drawn but it stays there permanently, so I need a way it will appear for a second and still use the Magic class.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first give the class an `image` attribute and during the instantiation call `self.start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()` to store the creation time.

Then add the instance to a list (or sprite group if you use a sprite subclass) and call the `update` method of the sprite each frame. In the `update` method you have to check if the life time of the instance has expired what you can do in this way: `if pygame.time.get_ticks() - self.start_time > 1500:`.

If you use sprites you can just call the `kill` method of the sprite when the time is up and it will be removed from all sprite groups. With a normal class and a list you'd have to iterate over the list and check which instance is still alive.

```
import pygame as pg


class Spell(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.Surface((5, 120))
        self.image.fill(pg.Color('sienna1'))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        self.start_time = pg.time.get_ticks()

    def update(self):
        # If current time - start time > 1500 milliseconds.
        if pg.time.get_ticks() - self.start_time > 1500:
            self.kill()  # Remove the instance from all sprite groups.


def main():
    screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()

    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                all_sprites.add(Spell(event.pos))

        all_sprites.update()
        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        all_sprites.draw(screen)

        pg.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pg.init()
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: You probably also want to know how to rotate a sprite and give it an offset: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42281315/6220679