# Python/ Pygame : 2d angular momentum / inertia

Tags: python, python-3.x, vector, pygame

my first ever Python program has hit a block I don't think I have the knowledge to solve myself.

It's a controllable spaceship on a 2d surface, I want to add momentum / inertia
I have it so the ship keeps travelling on the vector it previously was, when the engine is stopped.
However I can only get it to 'snap' to the new vector it rotates to face instantly.

What I want to happen is that inertia vector slowly aligns with the new pointing vector as it accelerates- like rotational acceleration? ( I'm not too hot on the math ) - I can rotate the inertia vector , but I would need to compare it somehow with the new pointing vector , and modify it based upon their difference?

if anyone could advise as to how I might start to approach this, that would be great - I suspect I coming at this from completely the wrong way.
Heres some of the code ( be gentle please!)

the sprite used is this : - [ship.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19hvq.png)

```
import pygame
import sys
from math import sin, cos, pi, atan2
from pygame.locals import *
import random
from random import randint
from pygame.math import Vector2
import operator

"""solar system generator"""
"""set screen size and center and some global namespace colors for ease of use"""
globalalpha = 255
screenx = int(1200)
screeny = int(700)
centerx = int(screenx / 2)
centery = int(screeny / 2)
center = (centerx, centery)
black = (  0,   0,   0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (209,   2,  22)
TRANSPARENT = (255,0,255)
numstars = 150
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((screenx, screeny), 0, 32)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
globaltimefactor = 1
shipimage = pygame.image.load('ship.png').convert()
DISPLAYSURF.fill(black)
screen_rect = DISPLAYSURF.get_rect()


class Playership(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.imageorig = pygame.image.load('ship.png').convert_alpha()
        self.startpos = (screen_rect.center)
        self.image = self.imageorig.copy()
        self.rect = self.imageorig.get_rect(center=self.startpos)
        self.angle = 0
        self.currentposx = 600
        self.currentposy = 350
        self.tuplepos = (self.currentposx, self.currentposy)
        self.speed = 1
        self.rotatespeed = 1.5
        self.initialvec = (600, 0)
        self.destination = 0
        self.anglechange = 0
        self.currentspeed = 0
        self.maxspeed = 5
        self.engineon = False
        self.newvec = (600, 0)
        self.newdestination = 0
        self.acceleration = 0.015
        self.inertiaspeed = 0
        self.transitionalvec = self.initialvec

    def get_angleafterstopping(self):
        newvec = self.initialvec
        self.newvec = newvec

    def get_destinationafterstopping(self):
        x_dist = self.newvec[0] - self.tuplepos[0]
        y_dist = self.newvec[1] - self.tuplepos[1]
        self.newdestination = atan2(-y_dist, x_dist) % (2 * pi)

    def get_destination(self):
        x_dist = self.initialvec[0] - self.tuplepos[0]
        y_dist = self.initialvec[1] - self.tuplepos[1]
        self.destination = atan2(-y_dist, x_dist) % (2 * pi)

    def moveship(self):
        if self.engineon is True:
            self.currentspeed = self.currentspeed + self.acceleration
            if self.currentspeed > self.maxspeed:
                self.currentspeed = self.maxspeed
            elif self.currentspeed < 0:
                self.currentspeed = 0
            self.inertiaspeed = self.currentspeed
        elif self.engineon is False:
            self.currentposx = self.currentposx + (cos(self.newdestination) * self.inertiaspeed * globaltimefactor)
            self.currentposy = self.currentposy - (sin(self.newdestination) * self.inertiaspeed * globaltimefactor)
            self.tuplepos = (self.currentposx, self.currentposy)
            self.rect.center = self.tuplepos
            return
        self.get_destination()
        self.currentposx = self.currentposx + (cos(self.destination) * self.currentspeed * globaltimefactor)
        self.currentposy = self.currentposy - (sin(self.destination) * self.currentspeed * globaltimefactor)
        self.tuplepos = (self.currentposx, self.currentposy)
        self.rect.center = self.tuplepos

    def rotateship(self, rotation):
        self.anglechange = self.anglechange - (rotation * self.rotatespeed * globaltimefactor)
        self.angle += (rotation * self.rotatespeed * globaltimefactor)
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageorig, self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
        initialvec = self.tuplepos + Vector2(0, -600).rotate(self.anglechange * globaltimefactor)
        initialvec = int(initialvec.x), int(initialvec.y)
        self.initialvec = initialvec




myship = Playership()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(myship)
firsttimedone = False


def main():

    done = False
    while not done:
        keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            myship.rotateship(1)
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            myship.rotateship(-1)
        if keys_pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
            myship.engineon = True
            myship.moveship()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    myship.engineon = False
                    myship.currentspeed = 0
                    myship.get_angleafterstopping()
                    myship.get_destinationafterstopping()
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(black)
        all_sprites_list.update()
        all_sprites_list.draw(DISPLAYSURF)
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, white, (myship.tuplepos), (myship.initialvec))
        pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, red, (myship.tuplepos), (myship.newvec))
        pygame.display.flip()
        if myship.engineon is False:
            myship.moveship()
        clock.tick(50)
        pygame.display.set_caption("fps: " + str(clock.get_fps()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    main()
    pygame.quit(); sys.exit();
```

**EDIT :**

I fixed it : just required a better understanding of vectors
ship starts off with acceleration and velocity both stated as vectors.

```
self.position = vec(screenx / 2, screeny / 2)
self.vel = vec(0, 0)
self.acceleration = vec(0, -0.2)  # The acceleration vec points upwards from the starting ship position
```

rotating the ship rotates that vector in place

```
self.acceleration.rotate_ip(self.angle_speed)
self.angle += self.angle_speed
self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageorig, -self.angle)
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
```

accelerating is this :

```
self.vel += self.acceleration * self.enginepower * globaltimefactor
```

updating position :

```
self.position += self.vel
self.rect.center = self.position
```

I was making it harder than it needed to be, velocity needed to be constant until acted upon by the rotated acceleration vector. I didn't know how to add vectors together etc.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve an effect like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42174811/6220679) (without the limit)?

Comment: I could show you some examples with moving ships/sprites, but the question is a bit unclear to me. So for example, when the user presses the left arrow key, the direction vector rotates counterclockwise and the ship slowly rotates towards this new direction/angle, but the velocity should stay the same. Is that correct? Or should the ship immediately accelerate in the new direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it : just required a better understanding of vectors
ship starts off with acceleration and velocity both stated as vectors.

```
self.position = vec(screenx / 2, screeny / 2)
self.vel = vec(0, 0)
self.acceleration = vec(0, -0.2)  # The acceleration vec points upwards from the starting ship position
```

rotating the ship rotates that vector in place

```
self.acceleration.rotate_ip(self.angle_speed)
self.angle += self.angle_speed
self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.imageorig, -self.angle)
self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)
```

accelerating is this :

```
self.vel += self.acceleration * self.enginepower * globaltimefactor
```

updating position :

```
self.position += self.vel
self.rect.center = self.position
```

I was making it harder than it needed to be, velocity needed to be constant until acted upon by the rotated acceleration vector. I didn't know how to add vectors together etc.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question after you figured it out! It helps future readers like me.